# saving float array to ascii

Tags: python, data-conversion

I need to convert an array of floats, 500e6 long, to an  ascii file. Doing this in a loop takes long time. I wander if there is a fast way for doing this.

I used a standard loop: NumSamples is 200e6; dataword is a vector of 200e6 values.

```
NumSamples=len(dataword)
for i in range(1,NumSamples):
    MyAscii=str(dataword[i])+"\n"
    fout.write(MyAscii)
```

python as language

Comment: you are writing on each loop, that takes time Disk write

Comment: As a side question, why are you storing your data as ascii as opposed to a more array efficient format like HDF5 ?

Comment: If you don't limit yourself to ascii, your can simply pickle the data. If you are not limited to built-in python functionality, numpy can format data as a string, probably way faster than this.

Comment: What type of "array"? Provide an example as code (smaller but otherwise the same as your real one).

Comment: I am using numpy, will look how numpy can handle float-2-string conversion. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try batching writes, so that you don't call `fout.write` every 4 bytes:

```
from itertools import batched
BATCH_SIZE = 1000
samples = iter(dataword)
# Skip first entry, like in the original code.
next(samples)
for batch in batched(samples, BATCH_SIZE):
    # Join 'BATCH_SIZE' floats in one string before writing it to file.
    MyAscii='\n'.join(map(str, batch))
    fout.write(MyAscii)
```

This will only call `fout.write` once every 1000 floats, at the cost of storing the string for 1000 floats in memory (negligible). As a rule of thumb, use the biggest `BATCH_SIZE` you can get without running out of memory.

---

Or, if you're using a Python version older than 3.12 that doesn't have [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched), here's a hand-rolled version:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 1000
NumSamples=len(dataword)
for batch_i in range(1,NumSamples,BATCH_SIZE):
    # Account for sample number not being divisible by batch size.
    limit = min(NumSamples, batch_i+BATCH_SIZE)
    # Join 'BATCH_SIZE' floats in one string before writing it to file.
    MyAscii='\n'.join(str(dataword[i]) for i in range(batch_i, limit))
    fout.write(MyAscii)
```

Comment: A slight efficiency improvement: `'\n'.join(map(str, batch))`

Comment: @MaurizioMastrofini Then you're using a Python version below 3.12. I've added an equivalent solution that doesn't use `batched`.

Comment: good suggestion, giving this a try and will post the results. only one small change:  
from itertools import batched gives an error, changed to from itertools import *

Comment: batched working. Big improvement reducing the number of writes to file  (10 times), about 2-3 minutes for one file  and  200M of float values. Now have to try with a 500Ms vector. thanks a lot this really helped.